# philosophy magazine which would cover new findings

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, publications

I have a question about which magazine or journal for general public would you recommend as the best to follow current developments in philosophy without geting into too much detail?

Due to last minute changes, I will have to teach an introductory course in history of philosophy next year, even though I come from a history department (specialising in intellectual history). I am well acquainted with the texts that I will be teaching but almost have no knowledge of contemporary philosophy. Since I will be teaching students of philosophy, I would like to try to make the course more relevant for them and at least mention some concurrent discussions in the class. Is there a journal or a magazine where I could quickly get an idea about what are the most relevant topics and questions being discussed at the moment? I am specifically looking for something that would be accessible to people without special training in philosophy, i.e. not academic journals.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK 'Philosophy Now' and 'The Philosophers' Magazine' - the first more basic than the second - give a reasonably reliable picture of the current state of philosophy in both the UK and the US. Subscription to these magazines has the extra benefit - certainly in the case of 'Philosophy Now' and I *believe* in that of 'The Philosophers' Magazine'also - of access to the archives. Both magazines are available online, so you can subscribe to them whatever your location.